# How should we stratify the space for Metropolis-Hastings?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings, stratification

Say I'm running Metropolis-Hastings with target density $p$. What I would like to do is divide the space $E$, on which $p$ is defined, into a disjoint union $E=\bigcup_iE_i$ and run a separate instance of Metropolis-Hastings inside each stratum $E_i$ (for example, since I can come up with a proposal kernel specifically designed for $E_i$).

Now, if I know nothing about $p$, how do I know what a smart choice for the stratification into the $E_i$ is? Intuitively, we somehow want that $E=\bigcup_iE_i$ is a decomposition of $p$ into its "modes", but what does that even mean in general (maybe that $p$ "does not vary too much inside each $E_i$?)?

Is there maybe some trial-and-error mechanism to detect the modes?

To make things simpler, please assume that $E=[0,1)^2$.

---

*EDIT*: Relevant articles on the web are:

- Stratification as a general variance reduction method for Markov chain Monte Carlo: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.08445.pdf
- Slides corresponding to the paper: [https://icerm.brown.edu/materials/Slides/tw19-2-hire/Computing_Rare_Event_Probabilities_by_Stratified_Markov_Chain_Monte_Carlo_]_Brian_Van_Koten,_University_of_Massachusetts-_Amherst.pdf](https://icerm.brown.edu/materials/Slides/tw19-2-hire/Computing_Rare_Event_Probabilities_by_Stratified_Markov_Chain_Monte_Carlo_%5D_Brian_Van_Koten,_University_of_Massachusetts-_Amherst.pdf)
- Xi'an's blog bost about this: https://xianblog.wordpress.com/2020/12/03/stratified-mcmc/

However, I don't know how I would use this in my case $E=[0,1)^2$ and an arbitrary $p$.